# Refresh song title without reloading the whole page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, shoutcast

I'm building a Shoutcast audio player with the information of the song/artist being played. I have two separate variables ($song and $artist) and their values are updated every time the song changes.

Here is an extract of the code:

```
<?php

$ip = "111.111.111";
$port = "9436";

$fp = @fsockopen($ip,$port,$errno,$errstr,1);
if (!$fp) 
    { 
    echo "Streaming offline momentaneamente"; // Displays when sever is offline
    } 
    else
    { 
    fputs($fp, "GET /7.html HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla\r\n\r\n");
    while (!feof($fp)) 
        {
        $info = fgets($fp);
        }
    $info = str_replace('</body></html>', "", $info);
    $split = explode(',', $info);
    if (empty($split[6]) )
        {
        echo "Streaming offline"; // Displays when sever is online but no song title
        }
    else
        {
        $title = str_replace('\'', '`', $split[6]);
        $title = str_replace(',', ' ', $title);
        $split = explode(' - ', $title);
        $artist = trim($split[0]);
        $song = trim($split[1]);
        }


    }

function truncate($string, $length, $dots = "...") {
    return (strlen($string) > $length) ? substr($string, 0, $length - strlen($dots)) . $dots : $string;
}

?>

<div class="player-item-ref acdc">
    <a class="player-link" href="#">
        <h2>AC/DC</h2>
        <ul><!-- THIS UL CONTAINS THE ITEMS TO BE REFRESHED -->
            <li class="song-title"><?php echo truncate("$song", 35); ?></li>
            <li class="song-artist"><?php echo truncate("$artist", 38); ?></li>
        </ul>
    </a>
</div><!-- /.player-container -->
```

I tried a 5 seconds refresh in JavaScript but it affects the whole page (including the player). I would to make a function which refresh these variables without reloading the whole page.

Comment: do you have any sample code or a fiddle?

Comment: But it seems you already know, how to solve it. You tagged your question "ajax", so yep, that's the right way - use AJAX to dynamically update just part of the page (DOM).

Comment: Hi Chris and Dawid, I've just added an extract of the code, I think I have to do something with AJAX.

Comment: Exactly. Just use script you have posted in your question as an endpoint I have described in my answer. You can print just text you want to display (song/artist info), but it would be better to envelope it to JSON/XML. But you can start with just text. Call that endpoint with JavaScript and periodically overwrite content of some tag with what it returns. You can google tons of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is in your question's tags: JavaScript, PHP and AJAX.

You need this things:

1. create an endpoint in PHP, which returns just song/artist information, for example formatted in JSON or XML
2. put JavaScript code in your page with the player, which periodically (for example once in 1 or 5 seconds) calls endpoint from point 1 (using for example JavaScript function `XMLHttpRequest`) and replace part of DOM, which contains song/artist information (probably DIV/SPAN with some ID)

That's all. That two things together are called [**AJAX**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). That abbreviation originally means *Asynchronous JavaScript and XML*, but you can use also JSON or plain HTML as response from your endpoint, not just XML. AJAX isn't a real thing, it's just a nickname for technique of asynchronous calls in JavaScript.

In a dumbest way: imagine you have this in your HTML page with a player:

`<div>Now playing: <span id="now_playing"></span></div>`

Create a JavaScript code, which will be executed each 1 second, it will call PHP script you have posted in your question, which returns currently played song as text without any other content (just "Artist - Song") and JavaScript code will put it (overwrite previous content) into span#now_playing. That's all.

Comment: Thanks for your response Dawid, I'll investigate further since I'm new in the world of Ajax and PHP.

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to ask, if you hang on something. But don't be afraid - AJAX really doesn't mean anything. It's just a nickname for asynchronous JavaScript calls.

Comment: You have marked my post as an answer. Does it mean, that you have solved that?

Comment: Yes! But instead of using JSON, I used jQuery+AJAX (https://matthewaprice.com/article/simple-jquery-ajax-auto-refreshing-div/) I'll keep improving! Thanks Dawid.

Comment: OK, great! But as I wrote, it's called AJAX even if you use JSON or plain text as you have used.